# How to resolve UnsatisfiedLinkError installing Spark on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, hadoop

I am trying to install Spark on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't.

What I have done is I have tried to install Spark with ./Spark but it is showing me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/opt/Spark/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: 
libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your error log file in [Spark directory]/logs/error.log. It will have some more information.
2. looks like you are trying to install 32-bit software on a 64-bit system and do not have the dependencies installed. I did not find a 64-bit version from a quick search.
3. If this is the case install it with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxrender1:i386
   ```

   Possibly you will get the same notice for ...

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxi6:i386
   sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
   ```

   and maybe some more.

   - The :386 will install the 32-bit version for you.
   - Install the 1st one and try that before installing the 2nd one and so on.